# multiple input value validation in parsley remote

Tags: jquery, parsley.js

I need to do a validation with two input fields in parsley remote. i.e

```
$('#user-name').parsley().addAsyncValidator('remotevalidator',remotevalidationfunction,'validation-url.htm');
```

The above example takes the value of user-name and passes it as a parameter to validation-url.htm. 
I need to pass value of another input field called `location`.

Please let me know how this can be done in parsley remote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do that with a remote validator. The best way to solve your issue is to use `$.ajax` and `addValidator`:

```
<input type="text" name="username" data-parsley-username />
<input type="text" name="location" id="location" />

<script>
window.ParsleyValidator
.addValidator('username', function (value, requirement) {
    var response = false,
        location = $("#location").val();    

    $.ajax({
        url: "validation-url.htm",
        data: {username: value, location: location},
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'get',
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            // if you send something from the server, you might want to 
            // do some verification here
            response = true;
        },
        error: function() {
            response = false;
        }
    });

    return response;
}, 32)
.addMessage('en', 'username', 'Username is invalid.');
</script>
```

Comment: `async: false` is now depreciated.